# Pass "select" name value to form action in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to pass option value to a form action in codeigniter ?

```
 <form class="form-inline space-top mb-0" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>instructor-search/<?php echo "?" ?>">
      <select name="location" class="form-control form-control-trans form-control-transs">
       </option value="name1">Name1</option>
       </option value="name2">Name2</option>
       </option value="name3">Name3</option>
       </option value="name3">Name4</option> 
      </select>
  </form>
```

here, I wanted to pass option value in action url in place of "?" at run time and then it redirect to action link.

Comment: With js only, but it's unclear why you need this.

Comment: actually i wanted a url link like www.something.com/"option selected value". i meant whatever i selected there, will be redirected to that page, I know i can do it easily by linking it to another page, but i have same page, where no.of things are there, and i wanted it on that page only.

Comment: Use onChange javascript/jQuery function to change the action value in form. There is no other option for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope its work for you

**Html code**

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://example.com/test">
<select id="chnageDrop">
        <option value="url1">URL1</option>
        <option value="url2">URL2</option>
        <option value="url3">URL3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$("#chnageDrop").change(function(){
    var baseUrl = 'https://example.com/test';
    var optionValue = this.value;
    var finalUrl = baseUrl + "&dropData=" + optionValue;
    $("#myForm").attr('action',finalUrl);
});
```

Comment: Hi Fairy, Thanks for your reply. It is working for me like i want.  currently , it is replacing my whole action url with the value i send. but i wanted to append it to the action url.I have used ".append" there in place of ".attr".but it is not working. what should i do for that..??

Comment: are you trying to submit the form after changing the dropdown?

Comment: I have changed some code in jQuery it add attributes to the action

Comment: Yes.Thank you so much.. Finally Its done like i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the GET method of form as below.

```
<form class="form-inline space-top mb-0" method="GET" action="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>instructor-search>
      <select name="location" class="form-control form-control-trans form-control-transs">
       </option value="name1">Name1</option>
       </option value="name2">Name2</option>
       </option value="name3">Name3</option>
       </option value="name3">Name4</option> 
      </select>
  </form>
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi Mohit,
Thanks for your reply. above  Fairy  is code is working for me.